# Posting to Devise from AngularJS (frontend) to reset password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm trying to enable password reset from AngularJS (front end) to Rails (back end).

But the JSON I'm posting doesn't resemble the hash that would be posted from a pure rails app, and I've been unable to replicate it.

**My JSON**

```
Parameters: {"email"=>"jim@example.com", "password"=>{"email"=>"jim@example.com"}}
```

**Rails app hash for same mechanism,**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "user"=>{"email"=>"jim@example.com"}, "commit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
```

Below is my current code for reference.

**Factory Action**

```
u.recoverPassword = function(email) {
    return $http.post('/users/password', email).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.emailForPassword = function() {
    users.recoverPassword(
            {email: $scope.emailForLostPassword}
        );
};
```

**View**

```
<form ng-submit="emailForPassword()">
    <div class="input-group form-field">
        <input type="email" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Email" ng-model="emailForLostPassword">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Log In">
</form>
```

Can anyone advise how to setup a proper `POST` to `Devise::PasswordsController#create` from AngularJS in order to reset user password?

(Ideally using $http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is expecting the params for password and email to be nested within the user hash. The line below needs to include the hash of params

```
return $http.post('/users/password', email).success(function(data) {
```

What is email? If you set up a variable to hold your params

```
var user_details = {email: "jim@example.com", password: "jim@example.com"}
```

Your post request can be

```
return $http.post('/users/password', user: user_details).success(function(data) {
```

Comment: It looks to be working at first but then responds with `406 Not Acceptable`, - implying an incorrect header?

Comment: Strictly speaking this is a separate question. 406 means that the response generated by the back end is not acceptable to the format supplied by the request. You probably need a [respond_block](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) in the corresponding controller action.